# Get all string in 1 file text start with character

Tags: c#

I have a text file. In the text file I have a string like below:

```
r=[{"\u7ec4ID",dataIndex:"id",key:"id"},{"\u7ec4\u540d\u79f0",dataIndex:"name",key:"name"}...
```

I want to get `\u7ec4ID`, `\u7ec4\u540d\u79f0` from that text file and put it in a string array.
I have the idea that this string usually starts with the character `"\u` and ends with `"` but I don't know how to parse it.

Can you help me?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: i have an idea: this string usually starts with the character `"\u` and ends with `"`

Comment: have you at least tried to loop through the string? RegEx is of course an option but there are several approaches beside RegEx.

Comment: [String.StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0) and [String.EndsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-6.0) should be great aid. The more you know the language you're using the better, as it means you have more tools to solve problems. I recommend that whenever you can, check through functions or even intellisense suggestions. You'll find many great tools to use.

Answer (score 0):

Load the text in your file into a string variable and use Regular expression and LINQ

```
string filePath = "..."; // Name of your file

var str = File.ReadAllText(filePath);            

var values = Regex
    .Matches(str, @"{""[\\a-zA-Z0-9]+""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .Select(s => s.Substring(2, s.Length - 3))
    .ToList();
```

`values` contains the values you wanted to retrieve.

---

```
var values = Regex
    .Matches(str, @"""\\u[\\a-zA-Z0-9]+""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .Select(s => s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: count value = 0. My string is longer, in question is just 1 cut in text file

Comment: I removed space after `{` character. Try again.

Comment: What I need to get out is usually inside the `"\u..."`

Comment: Your way is close to what I mean. But it doesn't start with `{`, usually starts with `"\u`

Comment: I added code. Try to compare with the first one. They work exactly the same.

Comment: @nqt95 the best way to say thank you here is to mark the answer that helped you as accepted

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper if it starts with `" \u` (white space) then how code for me?

Comment: Very easy. Search pattern would be `@""" \\u[\\a-zA-Z0-9]+"""` and extraction would be `s.Substring(2, s.Length - 3)`.

Comment: I want to combine both conditions with and without spaces. I have both `"\u` and `" \u"`

Comment: Use the first solution and add space `" "` into character group of search pattern -> `@"{""[\\a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"""`

Answer (score 0):

One option is parse as a Json but you need do some changes before deserialize. If you have this in your file:

```
r=[{"\u7ec4ID",dataIndex:"id",key:"id"},{"\u7ec4\u540d\u79f0",dataIndex:"name",key:"name"}]
```

We want this:

```
r=[{"id":"\u7ec4ID",dataIndex:"id",key:"id"},{"id":"\u7ec4\u540d\u79f0",dataIndex:"name",key:"name"}]
```

Basically, we do that your `"\u...` texts become the value part in the json. We create an artificial `id` property. Then, you can simply deserialize.

Create a class for your items:

```
public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string dataIndex { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: If you only need the id, you can remove the other properties.

And deserialize (you need the Newtonsoft nuget package):

```
// Read the file and "inject" the id property
var content = File.ReadAllText(...);
content = content.Replace("\"\\u", "\"id\":\"\\u");
        
// Remove the "r=" part to have only the array
var index = content.IndexOf('[');
content = content.Substring(index);

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(content);
var ids = items.Select(i => i.id);
```

Comment: This is not what I need